# An owned value is still references somehow

Tags: rust

I am using [Dashmap](https://github.com/xacrimon/dashmap). The [remove fn](https://github.com/xacrimon/dashmap/blob/1a31f4f5989fa42f5faa80ae0537e214d55cb0e4/src/lib.rs#L316) stats the following:

```
/// **Locking behaviour:** May deadlock if called when holding any sort of reference into the map.
```

This still deadlocks somehow, however, I don't hold any reference in the map, right?

```
use dashmap::DashMap;

fn main() {
    let map = DashMap::new();

    map.insert("hi".to_string(), 1);

    if let Some(i) = map.iter().next().map(|k| k.key().to_string()) {
        map.remove(&i);
    };
}
```

Variable `i` is an owned value, not borrowed. When I store `i` in a variable and use it later on, it works as expected. I was only surprised by the fact this code holds some sort of reference into `map`. I was wondering why this is the case. I guess this is not really related to the `Dashmap` library, but just how Rust works, that's why I am asking it here.

Answer (score 5):

The reference into the map is actually caused by the temporary iterator created by `map.iter()`. Since temporaries drop at the end of the statement, the iterator will stay alive for the entirety of the `if let` statement, thus locking the map from removes. You can fix this by explicitly storing the iterator in a variable and dropping it when needed:

```rust
use dashmap::DashMap;

fn main() {
    let map = DashMap::new();

    map.insert("hi".to_string(), 1);

    let mut map_iter = map.iter();
    if let Some(i) = map_iter.next().map(|k| k.key().to_string()) {
        std::mem::drop(map_iter);
        map.remove(&i);
    }
}
```

Or, my preferred method, getting the value an expression before in order to drop the temporary earlier:

```rust
use dashmap::DashMap;

fn main() {
    let map = DashMap::new();

    map.insert("hi".to_string(), 1);

    // iterator will be dropped after this let statement
    let opt = map.iter().next().map(|k| k.key().to_string());
    // there are now no references to the map
    if let Some(i) = opt {
        map.remove(&i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The temporary is dropped at the end of the statement specifically because this is an `if let` expression, but it's not always the case. For example, in a normal `if` statement, temporaries are dropped after the condition has been evaluated, but before the body is. ([Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ece23cb1fa36c6f2b9599eecdd5b21ac)). The [Destructors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes) page in the Rust Reference has the details.